# Simple multi-threading with SQLObject doesn't work

Tags: python, sqlobject

It stucks once I execute `.getOne()`:

```
from sqlobject import *
import threading

sqlhub.processConnection = connectionForURI('mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/database')

class Player(SQLObject):
    name = StringCol(length=64)
    last_login = DateTimeCol()
    create_date = DateTimeCol(default=DateTimeCol.now)

def act():
    result = Player.selectBy(name='Zippo')
    player = result.getOne()
    print 'You will never see this message in console.'

threading.Thread(target=act).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem was not related to SQLObject or Python. It was probably my computer or my MySQL server. Sorry for misquestioning everybody.

Answer (score 1):

could getOne be falling over, and you're just not seeing the exception? In this case you can specify a default result as an argument, or you could put it in a try/except clause.

What happens if you run it in a debugger?

there's not much info to go on here as we don't know what's in your database.

Comment: "It stucks once I execute .getOne()" - there is no exception, there is a long block. Whenenver I use it outside of the thread, everything works fine.

Comment: but could it be that you're not seeing the exception because it's in another thread? You haven't given much detail about what you've tried...

Comment: I have no idea why, but suddenly the exactly same code is working. Probably something was wrong with MySQL (a MySQL restart didn't help but a computer reboot did). Sorry for misquestioning :\